# Use an XmlWriter to fill the Powershell output stream line by line

Tags: powershell

It is possible to "open" the Powershell pipeline output stream as a `System.IO.Stream` or as `TextWriter`/`XmlWriter`?

Basically I want to convert some pipeline input strings or objects to Xml text using the services of XmlWriter like namespace handling and formatting capabilities. I want so send the result of conversion, incrementally, to the pipeline output, and not build the full output in one big string and send the whole output the the end.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly won't something really simple as this do what you want?

```
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter("c:\temp\output.xml",$Null)
Get-Content "file_with_input.txt" | foreach-object {[do your stuff with the XmlWriter]}
```

The lines from the input file will arrive one at a time and you can handle them as you please.

Comment: No, it's the opposite I want to do. I want to "link" the `XmlWriter` to the pipeline output, so that, when an `XmlWriter` method is called to write for example an Xml element, an appropriate string is sent immediately as pipeline output.

Comment: Without doing some really funky stuff that I honestly don't think would work very well I think you are stuck with Powershell convertto-xml then. The output is borderline atrocious imo.